# iMovie in iPad cannot find clips after sync with laptop

Tags: itunes, ipad, video, imovie

The kids have loved making movies in iMovie on the iPad. So much so that they filled it with their clips. So I synced to my laptop and selected the "delete from device" option in Photos figuring that iMovie had its own copy and it would free up space.

I was wrong. iMovie says "some videos in your project cannot be found because they were moved or deleted" and offers to search for them.

So I selected them on the laptop synced them back to the iPad again (unchanged, within a few minutes). iMovie cannot find them.

How do I repair this before the kids find out?

signed
Trembling Dad.

Comment: are they still on your Mac ?

Comment: yes they are. still in Photos.

Comment: than you are safe, just play dumb and ask who synced them to your Mac :)